# Difference of BETWEEN and greater or equal /less or equal

Tags: mysql

I want to find out if there is a difference in the result between using the two following queries on the same table:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE BETWEEN 01/01/2007 AND 30/9/2007
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE >= 01/01/2007 AND DATE <= 30/9/2007
```

Is there a difference between using `BETWEEN` and `>= <=`?

Comment: There is no difference. `between` is a shorter notation.

Comment: It is syntactic sugar

Comment: [what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Comment: I think you could figure this out for yourself

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM order_details WHERE order_date BETWEEN CAST('2014-02-01' AS DATE) AND CAST('2014-02-28' AS DATE);
```

This MySQL BETWEEN condition example would return all records from the order_details table where the order_date is between Feb 1, 2014 and Feb 28, 2014 (inclusive). It would be equivalent to the following SELECT statement:

```
SELECT * FROM order_details WHERE order_date >= CAST('2014-02-01' AS DATE) AND order_date <= CAST('2014-02-28' AS DATE);
```

[*Source*](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/between.php)

So the answer is **NO**, there is no difference